# c# ASP HttpResponse with redirect causes HTTP 302

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, redirect, http-status-code-302

I have a flow of web pages A and B.
On the web page A, I do a "Response.Redirect("B.aspx");
The page B needs a client certificate. When the redirect is done I see a popup asking for a client certificate. I select the correct certificate, which is retrieved from a smart card, and then I insert the pin. Right after, I see a page saying that the connection was lost, and I receive an HTTP 302. I never reach the page B.aspx. I tried to add the following line "Response.RedirectLocation = "B.aspx"; but with no success too.

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: Does B.aspx load if you navigate to it directly (instead of going to A.aspx first)? When you do, is there anything different about the client cert prompts?

Comment: Does this happen on all platforms or only on Windows 7? Smart cards are handled differently under windows 7, where the OS tries to load a card mini-driver for the inserted smart card and you'll get an error if Win7 can't find one for the inserted smart card.